# How setup.exe (without integrated JRE) searches for JRE on target machine?

Tags: install4j

We have an install4j based installer `setup.exe`. It comes without an integrated JRE which means that it runs only on machines with an installed JRE.

What is the algorithm used by install4j used for a JRE detection on the target system? What has to be set for install4j to be able to find a JRE? We install on Windows machines.

Answer (score 0):

The JRE search sequence is configured on the "General Settings->Java version" step. The "Search Windows registry and standard location" entry in that list searches the Windows registry for keys that are added by the Oracle JRE installer, including

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
```